# Can members of an inner class be overridden?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Suppose you have the following class declarations:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public virtual void DoSomething() { ... }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to override Bar.DoSomething() in a child class of Foo, a la:

```
public class Quz : Foo
{
    public override void Bar::DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Obviously that syntax doesn't work, but is something like this possible?

Comment: This kind of code is why I just avoid nested classes... I strongly suspect the answer is no; but I'll let someone with more experience with nested classes give a definitive answer.

Comment: I can see that. What's interesting to me is that the first code snippet compiles just fine, but there's no obvious way to actually override that virtual member.

Comment: @Didaxis Sure there is.  When you extend the actually class that you wish to override a member of, you can override it.  You're currently not extending it anywhere though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can still inherit from the `Foo.Bar` class itself:

```
public class BarDerived : Foo.Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

---

I feel I should explain that doing this will not mean that a class deriving from `Foo` will all of a sudden have an inner class of `BarDerived` instead, it just means that there is a class that can be derived from it. There are ways of replacing what type of class you want to use as the inner class, for example:

```
public class Foo<T>
    where T : Foo.Bar
{
    private T _bar = new T();

    public class Bar
    {
        public virtual void DoSomething() { ... }
    }
}

public class BarDerived : Foo.Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class Quz : Foo<BarDerived> { ... }
```

Comment: @Didaxis You didn't know that you could override a virtual member when extending the class with a virtual member?

Comment: @Servy of course I did, I was just tripped-up on it being an inner class.

Answer (score 1):

No, only if you inherit from `Bar`

```
public class Quz : Foo.Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are following good practices, then the `Bar` cannot be constructed by any other class then `Foo`, that said enables the following:

Create a derived class from `Foo::Bar` in `Quz`, and override it's `DoSomething()`
override each method in `Foo` where `Bar` is constructed and provide the derived class instead.

the user of `Foo` should not know the difference in API between `Bar` and your new derived inner class.

hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that is exactly my intended use here -where users do not know the underlying implementation differences of Bar.